# ERROR: The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, circleci, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to deploy using CircleCI -> S3 -> CodeDeploy -> EC2.
I was able to upload deploy image onto S3 from CircleCI, but unable to deploy S3 to EC2 instance. Here's the error.

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances
> failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for
> deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are
> experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

The error was provided from CodeDeploy. I can't figure out why and how.
I'd appreciate if you give some advise.

Answer (score 21):

If you are running on Ubuntu there might be plenty of reasons, here is a checklist can verify

Check code-deploy agent is installed on your EC2 Instance. Please refer this document to install code deploy agent.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-ubuntu.html

```
$ sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

In case if you are running Ubuntu release 20.x and you get this error

> ./install:22:in `block in method_missing': undefined method` path' for
> #<IO:> (NoMethodError)

try running the install file via this script

```
sudo ./install auto > /tmp/logfile
```

1. Check you have EC2 Instance Code Deploy Role -> Create a code deployment role and assign it to the Instance, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html.

> In case if you assign the EC2 Role after initiate, restart the server.

2. Check your appsec.yml file placement as per the top answer, try to avoid any long timeout in it.
3. Log into your instance check your error log

`$ tail -f /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`

Comment: that `tail` command saved me, ty

Comment: I attached the role after the instance was launched. Did not know, I should reboot the server. Thanks! Working fine.

Answer (score 5):

This error is commonly due to problems in the configuration of the `appSpec.yml` or `appSpec.json` file (It depends on the format you are using).

"If you have any Hook I recommend that you remove them, check if it works, then you can add one by one (the Hooks) and so you can identify the error"

The `appspec.yml` file should be located at the root of your project:

```
   │-- appspec.yml
   │-- index.html
   └-- scripts
       │-- install_dependencies
       │-- start_server
       └-- stop_server
```

In the `scripts` folder you will have to place the processes that you want to be executed according to the **Hook**

Here is an example of the `appspec.yml` file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /index.html
    destination: /var/www/html/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

I hope I can help you

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to figure out what caused the individual instances to fail by digging into the deployment instance details:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-view-instance-details.html

These should contain more detailed information about why your application was unable to be deployed.

Comment: After reviewing /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log , I've noticed some error on IAM service role. But it seems like configured correctly. CodeDeploy Full Access is there on that. Any idea?

Comment: For the role assigned to your EC2 instance, you'll want to configure it for permissions to pull from S3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html. It shouldn't need the CodeDeploy Full Access permissions.

Comment: Thanks. Finally it works. It's a matter of way of format of YAML. I checked some log from CodeDeploy config. And modified along with your doc.

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa could you please share your solution?

Comment: @Adnan Sorry for that. I wrote my solution above. Hope it help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the **CodeDeploy Host Agent Service** is running in your target EC2 instance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error you are facing is a generic error message thrown on any of the event failure which could be beforeblockTraffic, blockTraffic, ApplicationStop etc.

[image]

The [first step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-verify.html#codedeploy-agent-operations-verify-linux) in this case would be check whether code deploy agent is running or not if first event i.e. BeforeBlockTraffic event is failed.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the event failure message would tell you the exact error behind.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the failed deployments, I can see all lifecycle events were skipped. Instance i-0bcc36e73851297f2 is currently in Stopped state but I can see the IAM instance profile is missing. Your Amazon EC2 instances need permission to access the Amazon S3 buckets or GitHub repositories where the applications that will be deployed by AWS CodeDeploy are stored. To launch Amazon EC2 instances that are compatible with AWS CodeDeploy, you must create an additional IAM role, an instance profile. [1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html)

For such failures, you can always begin with a general troubleshooting checklist for a failed deployment [2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-general.html) and then look for troubleshooting guides on Deployment Issues and Instance issues[3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html).

[1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html)[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html][1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html)

[2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-general.html) [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-general.html][2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-general.html)

[3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html) [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html][3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the Code Deploy Agent. In my case, the agent wasn't up.

Comment: Dupe of previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the role given to the ec2 machine(where the agent is running). It should have s3 access as well. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

"The CodeDeploy agent did not find an AppSpec file within the unpacked revision directory at revision-relative path 'appspec.yml'"

Please place your appspec.yml file in your root folder to solve this error

To access your after script and before script